# How to display 2 select statement output through stored procedure in db2 under if condition

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

Based on OutPutType=1, I need to display 2 select statement output. In the below code I am getting following error: (Please note In actual I have 2 different dataset in 2 select statement but here for reference I have written one select for time and another statement used for date)

SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "OM sysibm.sysdummy1'".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.21.29

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE Test.Test1 ( 
IN OutPutType SMALLINT)

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2 LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC test1
BEGIN
DECLARE v_cursor_text VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE v_cursor_text1 VARCHAR(5000);

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement1;
DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement2;

 IF OutPutType = 1 THEN

 SET
v_cursor_text = ' SELECT CURRENT_TIME   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
        
v_cursor_text1 = 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
        
END IF;

 PREPARE Statement1
FROM
v_cursor_text;
 PREPARE Statement2
FROM
v_cursor_text1;

OPEN c1;
OPEN C2;
END
```

Comment: If your procedure can have TWO distinct result-sets then you must use `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2` when creating the procedure, and in the case that you only have 1 result-set then the second result-set must yield no rows.  This might be considered a poor design.

Comment: @mao I tried doing with dynamic result set 2 but still got the same error

Comment: your syntax error results from your example procedure missing a `SET` before `c_cursor_text1`.     Fix your syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax error results from a missing `SET` verb before `v_cursor_text1`.

To get the procedure to compile, your sample should read:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test.Test1 ( IN OutPutType SMALLINT)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2 
LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC test1
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_cursor_text VARCHAR(5000);
    DECLARE v_cursor_text1 VARCHAR(5000);

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement1;
    DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement2;

    IF OutPutType = 1 THEN
        SET v_cursor_text = ' SELECT CURRENT_TIME   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
        set v_cursor_text1 = 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
    END IF;

    PREPARE Statement1 FROM v_cursor_text;
    PREPARE Statement2 FROM v_cursor_text1;
    OPEN c1;
    OPEN C2;
END@
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show two select statements for "OutputType=2"...

The only select statements you set are for "OutputType=1"

also, you have `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1` but open both cursors...so you should have `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2`

Neither of the select statements you show need to be dynamic, you could simply use a

```
DECLARE C1 cursor for
  SELECT CURRENT_TIME FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Hopefully you aren't actually intending to get the date and time this way...

Lastly you should tag the question with the actual Db2 platform, not both db2-400 and db2-luw.

Comment: Hi Charles, those 2 select statements are dummy in nature... I have 2 different data set which I need to display for Output Type=1...

Answer (score 0):

Use only one cursor. Build SQL statement based on input parameter.

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement1;
    
IF OutPutType = 1 THEN
 SET v_cursor_text = ' SELECT CURRENT_TIME   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
else       
 set v_cursor_text  = 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1';
END IF;

PREPARE Statement1
FROM
v_cursor_text ;

Open c1;
```

Comment: hi @satya, when output type is 1 then I need to show both select statement output. One is detail output and other is summary output. So in this case I cannot use if else within select statement.